# What does "With a team" mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning

Does the phrase "with a team" imply that the speaker is on the team, or rather that the speaker is explicitly *not* on the team (of course it may also be ambiguous)?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: _I won a gold medal with a team of great players. I plowed the field with a team of oxen._ I would guess that the speaker is _on_ the team in the first sentence, and _not_ on the team in the second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence fragment, "with a team," does not give sufficient indication as to whether the speaker is on the team or not. In this case you are right to say that it may be ambiguous, but mostly due to the lack of context you provided. To say that one "works with a team" would indicate that they are not really on the team, perhaps in a management role. On the other hand, to say that one "plays with a team" would suggest that they are on the team. Could you provide a broader context for your question?

Comment: This is on a resume, but as a standalone fragment, not a paragraph.

Comment: If you are asking for more details, then you are not writing an answer; it is rather a comment.